# Block access to certain variables within function

Tags: javascript

How can I make a function which was originally defined elsewhere in my code be denied or limited access to certain objects when it gets assigned to an object?

**Short Example**

```
var func = function() {
  console.log(window.screenX); // <-- this should work
  document.createElement("div"); // <-- this should fail (ideally in 
                                 //     some graceful way)
};

var makeObj = function(pFunc) {
  var window = {
    "screenX": window.screenX
  };
  var document = null;
  var rObj = {};
  rObj.func = pFunc;
  return rObj;
};

var obj = makeObj(func);

obj.func(); // <-- want it to have no access to document and
            //     limited access to window
```

`func` is defined by privileged users as a sort of plugin but I want to limit what they can do such as not creating new elements  but still be able to access certain variables and functions they will need (such as `window.screenX`)

Comment: I would start by referencing `pFunc` instead of `func`, otherwise it may not work as intended. http://prntscr.com/hhsyzh . You may work with custom `.apply` anyway, though you may not be able to limit literally everything.

Comment: Typo, that's what it's supposed to be, sorry. Fixed

Comment: There's more than just the example I want to limit, but I don't need to limit everything. Mostly my focus is removing access to the ability to modify anything outside of a certain `div` they will be given. It's not web facing, it's running in an electron app for a non critical application so not perfect is fine, I just want to have some level of restriction to discourage it or at least make it difficult and not worth the effort.

Comment: Look into Adsafe http://www.adsafe.org/. They've been doing stuff like this for years.

Comment: I don't think you can limit something so fundamental as `createElement();` that's in an anonymous function...In fact don't use anonymous functions first of all. Try using namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there are tons of possible answers, my answer make use of the [Function-constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) so that `window` and `document` are defined locally within the scope of an also locally defined function. This is very important because you do not want to overwrite  both objects globally.

But lets come to this answer. Within `makeObj` all allowed objects in `func` are defined with the first and second param of a `new Function`-Constructor.

The third param is used to create an "anonymous" function that contains certain assignments to those allowed objects. These assignments were created locally by using `serializeFakeObject`.

In other words, the first and second param with `new Function` are going to be the params (header or signature) while the third param is going to be the body of the „anonymous“ function.

Please note that this "anonymous" function is created dynamically and looks like this afterwards:

```
function anonymous(window,document) {
      // overwrites allowed objects 
      window = {"screenX":-8};
      document = {};
      document.createElement = function (){ throw Error("document.createElement is not allowed"); };

      // this function must take assignments above
      // no chance to use the globally defined objects window or document
      return function (){
          console.log(window);
          console.log(document.createElement());
      }();
}
```

This anonymous function is dynamically created within `makeObj` and after that executed by calling `obj.func()` at the end.

Lets put all together:

```
var func = function (){
    console.log(window); // has just got screenX
    console.log(document.createElement()); //  throws an error "document.createElement is not allowed"

};

var makeObj = function(pFunc) {

    var serializeFakeObject = function(name,obj){
        var serializedObject = "";
        // when its a property of type function then omit JSON.stringify otherwise it gets undefined
        if(obj.__proto__.constructor === Function)serializedObject = obj;
        else serializedObject = JSON.stringify(obj);
        return name + ' = ' + serializedObject + ';';
    };

    var fakeWindow = serializeFakeObject("window", { "screenX": window.screenX });
    var fakeDocument = serializeFakeObject("document", {});
    // create property createElement of document that should fail in a graceful way
    var fakeDocumentProperty = serializeFakeObject("document.createElement", function (){ throw Error("document.createElement is not allowed"); });
    // if you like you can add more properties here....

    var concatFakeObjects = fakeWindow+fakeDocument+fakeDocumentProperty;
    var rObj = {};
    // the line below creates the "anonymous" function described above
    rObj.func = new Function('window', 'document', concatFakeObjects +'return '+pFunc+'();');
    return rObj;
};

var obj = makeObj(func);

console.log(obj.func());
```